# Object has no attribute '.__dict__' in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a test that passes in Python2 and fails in Python3, I'm trying to find out why. The test fails at the following line:

```
self._timeseries[0].resource.__dict__
```

With the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

If I debug the test, and print the object in the debugger, I can see the following:

```
(Pdb) p self._timeseries[0].resource.__dict__
OrderedDict([('type', 'type_value'), ('labels', {'label1': 'value1', 'label2': 'value2', 'label3': 'value3'})])
```

If I do the same in Python3 debugger, I get this:

```
(Pdb) p self._timeseries[0].resource.__dict__
*** AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? The object looks exactly the same if I print it in the debugger without the `.__dict__`, why is this failing for Python3?

Comment: Perhaps whatever library changed this type to a `__slots__` object in python3?  It's really impossible to know without seeing the class definition and more information.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the dynamically defined properties in that case? Doing `.__slots__` returns just `()`.

Comment: This is rather surprising. What is `self.timeseries[0].resource` exactly supposed to be? When I check the `__dict__` of an arbitrary object, in both Python 2 and 3, I get an object of `dict` type, not of `OrderedDict` type. My guess is, the way you get Python 2 to set to `resource` a `__dict__` attribute of `OrderedDict` type does not work in Python 3.

Comment: @Rightleg You're right, that's interesting. I can't easily find out though, so I guess I'll never know how this ended up being the case.

Comment: Surprising as it may sound, I was playing with named tuples, and I found some weird thing: when you create a named tuple and then instantiate it, that instance's `__dict__` is an `OrderedDict`. Could it be that your Python 2 test imports `collections`, while your Python 3 test forgets to do it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So I found the answer after some digging, this indeed is a difference between Python2 and Python3, a nuisant one at that.

It turns out the type `Resource` in the code is actually a named tuple. In Python2, `.__dict__` is added as convenient property wrapper of `._asdict()`, but this isn't done in Python3:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict (find `__dict__` here)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict

So it looks like `._asdict` is in fact the source of truth, and should be used for portable 2to3 code.

It's worth mentioning that `vars` is also a wrapper that exists in Python2 only.

Comment: Neat!  I didn't know there used to be a `__dict__` on `namedtuple`, I'm glad they removed it :).  `vars` does exist in python3 as well

Comment: I just commented something like that on your original question, just to see that you had already posted this answer. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: Note: `vars` exists in Py2 and Py3, but it's basically a thin-wrapper that's equivalent to looking up `__dict__` on the argument given, so when they fixed the bug with `namedtuple`, it stopped working. User-defined classes that use `__slots__` throughout the inheritance hierarchy (none of which have a `__dict__` slot) will always have this problem, since they replace `__dict__` use with (effectively) a bunch of class level properties that access values stored in the C level object metadata that has no equivalent to `__dict__`.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a little function, I'm probably missing a few edge cases but it satisfied the few little testcases I wrote (probably broken for multiple inheritance)

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1


class D(object):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 1


class E(D):
    __slots__ = ()


class F(D):
    __slots__ = ('z',)
    def __init__(self):
        super(F, self).__init__()
        self.z = 1


def vars2(x):
    if hasattr(x, '__dict__'):
        return vars(x)
    else:
        ret = {slot: getattr(x, slot) for slot in x.__slots__}
        for cls in type(x).mro():
            spr = super(cls, x)
            if not hasattr(spr, '__slots__'):
                break
            for slot in spr.__slots__:
                ret[slot] = getattr(x, slot)
        return ret


def main():
    print(vars2(C()))
    print(vars2(D()))
    print(vars2(E()))
    print(vars2(F()))
    OUTPUT = '''\
{'y': 1, 'x': 1}
{'y': 1, 'x': 1}
{'y': 1, 'x': 1}
{'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'z': 1}
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

Comment: This is great, I do applaud the effort! This should work. However in my case I only needed to call `._asdict()`, please take a look at my answer below.